# Set Session in Asp page using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, asp-classic

I have a Login Page which is created in asp.net now when i successfully logins into my application i need to transfer session related information from my asp.net page to my asp page so how to set my session information in asp using asp.net.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to share session state between classic asp and asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx)

Comment: Hello Hasan Khan thanks for your reply.... I have memory based state server rather than sql server so can you tell me how can i set session using asp.net in my asp page

Answer (score 1):

I see you mentioned wanting to use State Server. You could try NSession it allows sharing session state between Classic ASP and ASP.Net using State server. Pretty easy to setup just configure App to use State Server for session and register a couple of dll files.